# I get 20 errors in the algorithm file when trying to sort a struct vector. I don't know what is wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, struct

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <struct.h>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct points {
    int x,y;
};

bool operator<(const points &p1, const points &p2) {
    return p1.x<p2.x;
};

vector<points> a(1000000);
int i,n,closest;

int main() {

    scanf("%d\n",&n);

    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d\n",&a[i].x,&a[i].y);
    }

    sort(0,n-1,a);

    return 0;
}
```

The errors that I get mostly state "Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid). What could be wrong? I'm trying to sort the structs within the vector. I have used operator overload.

Comment: try bool operator<(const points p1, const points p2) without the &

Comment: What debugging have you tried?

Comment: thanks but it didn't work

Comment: The entire program didn't have any errors (I tested it many times) and when I added the sort it had 20 so that's all i did

Comment: You should refrain from mixing C++ and C together. Get rid of that `scanf` and use C++ streams (i.e. `std::cin >> a[i].x` &co.).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort <-- look there, what std::sort's argumenst are.

Comment: Why not resize the vector to `n` instead of making it huge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you use `std::sort`! Replace:

```
sort(0, n-1, a);
```

with:

```
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
```

Comment: Also, declare `vector<points> a(n);` inside `main`, instead of `vector<points> a(1000000);` at global scope. Otherwise, you will be sorting also the elements you did not read from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct points {
    int x,y;
};

bool operator<(const points &p1, const points &p2) {
    return p1.x<p2.x;
};

vector<points> a;
int i,n,closest;

int main() {
    cin >> n;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        points p;
        cin >> p.x >> p.y;
        a.push_back(p);
    }

    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << a[i].x << ',' << a[i].y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```